# The google map in my web app appears wrong on tablet

Tags: android, google-maps, cordova, screen

I try to run a google map in my cordova application. It displays well on mobile (Iphone 5s) but not on my tablet (Nexus 7).

Here my map display function :

```
function onSuccessMap() {

var myLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE);

if (map === null)
{
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({suppressMarkers: true});

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('directionMap'), {
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center: myLocation,
        disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
        zoom: 8
    });

    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

}



}
```

The map appears at the top left of the screen and doesn't take up all the space.

I hope I have given enough information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to set the width and height of the div containing the map (#directionMap).

(the div should take the space independently. The map will not make the div bigger). Nexus 7 runs probably KitKat, and the difference stems from Chromium vs. Webkit.